# How to share data between other microservices in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, microservices, spring-cloud

I am learning about microservices through spring boot cloud. I have 2 services `authenticate` and `product` and I call them both through the `gateway`, I encounter the following problem:

- How can the product service know which user has logged in from the    authenticate service and retrieve that user's login information?
- In the `product service`, I have a `products table` and it has a `createdBy column` that is the user stored in the `users table` at the `authenticate service`. How can I get creator information when getting list of products similar to Left Join?
- How to share data between other services?

In my project, each service will have a separate database, is that optimal?

I've been working on this for a few hours and still have no results, it seems quite difficult to do. Select the solution you're using. Thank you and happy coding

Comment: This question seems more suited for the SE stack exchange - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is typically what OAuth2 solves: you `authenticate` service looks pretty much like an *OAuth2 authorization server* and your `product` service like an *OAuth2 resource server*.

If you had an *OAuth2 client* (like the gateway could be), then it could get an access token from the authorization server and authorize its requests to the resource server using this token. Resource server gets the info it needs about the client and the resource owner (authenticated user in your case) from the token (decoding it if it's a JWT or introspecting it on the authorization server otherwize).

The bad news is you can probably trash your `authenticate` service as OIDC providers like Keycloak or cloud offers like Cognito, Auth0, Okta, etc. do probably more and better than what you did. The good news being that this services exist already, actually do a lot (user registration, clients management, identity federation, multi-factor authentication, ...), are well documented, and are not that difficult to configure.

More details in my [OAuth2 essentials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials) and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Normally a user in the authentication service is identified by a unique synthetic key (user ID) which is created during the user registration. You can store the value of this key in your `createdBy` column of the product service. The necessary key should be passed to the product service as an argument of its REST API.

If case the product service needs more information about the user than just that user ID, you should foresee a dedicated REST API endpoint in the authentication service which returns the necessary info by the user ID.

I believe you should look into Spring Security, it supports many typical authentication workflows. For more info see, for example, a [series of videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEocw3gLFc8XRaRBZkhBEZ_R3tmvfkWZz) by Laurentiu Spilca on the subject, particularly regarding OAuth2 authentication server.